# ORA-14188: sub-partitioning columns must form a subset of key columns of a UNIQUE index

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have a table created with the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE "RATEDEVENT" 
(   
    "CREATED_TIME" NUMBER, 
    "SESSION_ID" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "SCHEMA_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "RATED_EVENT" BLOB, 
    "PARTITION_TIME" NUMBER
) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 60 INITRANS 80 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS  LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 204800 NEXT 204800 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 20971520 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) 
  PARTITION BY LIST ("PARTITION_TIME") AUTOMATIC 
  SUBPARTITION BY HASH ("SESSION_ID") 
  SUBPARTITIONS 32
 (PARTITION "OLD_TIME"  VALUES (-1) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 60 INITRANS 80 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 204800 NEXT 204800 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 20971520 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) 
 ( SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP933" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP934" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP935" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP936" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP937" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP938" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP939" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP940" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP941" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP942" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP943" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP944" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP945" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP946" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP947" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP948" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP949" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP950" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP951" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP952" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP953" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP954" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP955" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP956" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP957" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP958" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP959" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP960" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP961" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP962" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP963" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP964" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 LOB ("RATED_EVENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) ) ;
```

I am trying to create a unique index but am unsure how to do it. Currently using the following query:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "IB_RATEDEVENT" ON "RATEDEVENT" ("PARTITION_TIME", "CREATED_TIME") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 80 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 20971520 NEXT 20971520 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) LOCAL
 (PARTITION "OLD_TIME" NOCOMPRESS 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 80 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 20971520 NEXT 20971520 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
 ( SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP933" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP934" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP935" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP936" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP937" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP938" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP939" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP940" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP941" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP942" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP943" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP944" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP945" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP946" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP947" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP948" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP949" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP950" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP951" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP952" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP953" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP954" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP955" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP956" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP957" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP958" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP959" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP960" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP961" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP962" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP963" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" , 
  SUBPARTITION "SYS_SUBP964" 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ECE" ) ) ;
```

When trying to create index I get error:

> ORA-14188: sub-partitioning columns must form a subset of key columns of a UNIQUE index

How should I change my create index SQL statement to fix this?

Comment: It's best to post the actual SQL you use when creating tables and indexes, rather than a 500 line dump from dbms_metadata complete with storage settings that aren't related to the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's a restriction of partitioning that any unique index/constraint that you want to be partitioned the same way as its table must share the same partition keys. The table is partitioned by PARTITION_TIME and SESSION_ID, so the unique index needs to include those columns too.

```
create table ratedevent 
( created_time     number
, session_id       varchar2(4000)
, schema_id        number(*,0)
, rated_event      blob
, partition_time   number )
lob (rated_event) store as basicfile
partition by list (partition_time) automatic 
subpartition by hash (session_id) 
subpartitions 32
( partition old_time  values (-1) );
```

```
create unique index ib_ratedevent on ratedevent 
(partition_time, session_id, created_time)
local;
```

If it wasn't unique, it wouldn't need to:

```
create index ib_ratedevent2 on ratedevent (created_time) local;
```